# Can `content_scripts` detect if a `command` is set?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, browser-extension

My extension currently uses the `[esc]` key to perform an action.

This is done in the content-script, using `addEventListener('keydown')`.

I'd like the user to be able to choose a different shortcut.

I've updated to Manifest V3, and added a new `"commands"` key, i.e.

```json
{
    ...
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
            "service_worker": "background.js"
        },
    "content_scripts": [ {
            "js": [ "screenshot.js" ],
            "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]
         }],
    "commands": {
        "stop-animations": {
            "description": "Stop Animations"
        }
    }
}
```

I've updated `background.js` to use `chrome.commands.onCommand`, and this works well.

But, how can I get my content-script to determine if the user has set their own shortcut?

Because I should not listen to the 'keydown' event to check if they have pressed the `[esc]` key.

I've tried using `chrome.commands.getAll()`, but this method is only available at install time.

A partial option would be to use something like `browser.storage` to set a simple boolean "custom-command-set" to true whenever `onCommand` is used, but I cannot think of a way to switch it off again if the user deletes the shortcut command (i.e. they want to go back to using the `[esc]` key).

At the moment I don't have a toolbar icon (action default_popup), or any other UI, and I'd prefer to not add one just to provide a custom way to set the shortcut.

Comment: "I've tried using chrome.commands.getAll(), but this method is only available at install time." -- That's not true. The [chrome.commands](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/commands/) documentation doesn't say this, and a small test extension I wrote can call chrome.commands.getAll() from background.js anytime.

Comment: chrome.commands API won't help here because it can't assign to a single key like Esc, it requires Ctrl or Alt. You'll have to use standard DOM methods both in the content script and in the options page (or the popup) to configure the key.

Comment: @ThomasMueller, thanks, you're right, I thought I saw the "only at install time" limitation somewhere, I'm sure it was discussing user privacy (I'd tried using it in the content-script, but rather than checking in the background-script, I must have mis-read something). Want to add that as an answer for some more SO points?

Comment: @wOxxOm, yep, thanks for confirming, I'm trying to support both, by using the normal DOM "keydown" in the content script to pick up the [esc] key... but I need to remove that event if the user has set a custom keyboard shortcut... and I think I've got that working by using addEventListener(), then perform the slow-ish process of calling chrome.runtime.sendMessage() to the background script, which checks chrome.commands.getAll(), and if that works, and a shortcut has been set, call chrome.tabs.sendMessage() to the content script, which will removeEventListener().

Comment: And by "slow-ish", I mean 40 milliseconds (0.04 seconds) on a fast desktop computer... which is fine, but I don't want to wait for an async process to complete, on page load, to add the [esc] shortcut.

Comment: @CraigFrancis - Is it any faster with `sendResponse()`, like it's done in the answer, instead of `chrome.tabs.sendMessage()`?

Comment: Thanks @ThomasMueller, it does seems to be a bit quicker using `sendResponse()`, at 30ms (and the occasional sub 10ms response), where I've also taken out the `console.log` and simply used `chrome.commands.getAll().then(sendResponse)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content scripts can't call `chrome.commands.getAll()` directly, so they need to send a message to the service worker. The SW calls `chrome.commands.getAll()` and sends the result back to the content script.

`manifest.json`

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "chrome.commands.getAll",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "background": {
          "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": [ "content_script.js" ],
            "matches": [ "*://*/*" ]
        }
    ],
    "commands": {
        "test": {
            "description": "Test"
        }
    },
    "permissions": ["commands"]
}
```

`background.js`

```
function commands_on_command(command) {
    console.log("on_command", command);
}

function runtime_on_message(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message == "get_all_commands") {
        chrome.commands.getAll()
        .then(commands => {
            console.log("background.js", "runtime_on_message", commands);
            sendResponse(commands);
        });
        return true; // https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#simple
    }
    else {
        console.log("background.js", "runtime_on_message", "unknown command");
        sendResponse("unknown command");
    }
}

chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(commands_on_command);
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(runtime_on_message);
```

`content_script.js`

```
(async () => {
    let response = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage("get_all_commands");
    console.log("content_script.js", response);
})();
```